# .Net Core 6 routing with regex constrains

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using .Net core 6 web-API

I want to add to a controller some regex constraints but I keep getting an error.

**controller**:

```
    [Route("module/{module:regex(^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,80}$)}/lang/{lang:regex(^[a-zA-Z]{3}$)}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDictionary([System.Web.Http.FromUri] string module, string lang)
    {
        // some code
    }
```

**Program.cs** (HTTP PIPELINE)

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMiddleware<RequestInterceptorMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

app.UseCors(GeneralConsts.AllowedOrigins);
app.UseResponseCaching();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

**Error**

```
System.ArgumentException: 'In a route parameter, '{' and '}' must be escaped with '{{' and '}}'. (Parameter 'routeTemplate')'
```

I have tried to add the '{}' as the compiler suggests but it doesn't help.

```
[Route("module/{{module:regex(^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,80}$)}}/lang/{{lang:regex(^[a-zA-Z]{3}$)}}")]
```

I tried looking online but with no luck.
Does anyone know the cause of the issue? and how can I fix it?

Comment: There are `{` and `}` *inside* the regex that need escaping. Try `[Route("module/{module:regex(^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{{2,80}}$)}/lang/{lang:regex(^[a-zA-Z]{{3}}$)}")]`

Comment: @DavidG Thanks! I tried but I'm actually getting another error now: 

"Error 1:
For action: 
Error: While processing template 'api/elalDictionary/module/{module:regex(^[a-zA-Z0-9.]{{2,80}}$)}/lang/{lang:regex(^[a-zA-Z]{{3}}$)}', a replacement value for the token 'a-zA-Z0-9.' could not be found. Available tokens: 'action, controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a literal string in a route or within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]' instead.'"